# how to change quantity of product in

Tags: angular

i am making shopping cart project in which i am suppose to increase or decrease the quantity. i have quantiy(spelling mistake in database) which i want to to increase or decrease but nothing is happening on clicking

```
 <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
      <img
        class="card-image"
        src="{{ product.imageUrl }}"
        alt="{{ product.name }}"
      />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{ product.name }}</h5>
        <p class="card-text"><span>price:Rs</span>{{ product.price }}</p>
        <div class="quantity-container">
          <div class="quantity">
            <button
              type="button"
              class="btn quantity-btn"
              (click)="decrease(product._id)"
            >
              <mat-icon>remove</mat-icon>
            </button>
            <span>{{ product.quantiy }}</span>
            <button
              type="button"
              class="btn quantity-btn"
              (click)="increase(product._id)"
            >
              <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

my typescript file

```
export class TestdataComponent implements OnInit {
  quantity: number = 0;
  constructor(private testDataService: TestDataService) {}

  increase(id: any): void {
    let x = this.products.find((product) => product._id === id);
    x.quantity = x.quantiy + 1;
    console.log(x);
  }
  increase(id: any): void {
    let x = this.products.find((product) => product._id === id);
    x.quantity = x.quantiy - 1;
    console.log(x);
  }
}
```

Comment: Take quantity variable as an array.

Comment: @VinaySomawat please can you ellaborate as how can i use array to resolve this?

Comment: In the method `increase` the parameter `id` is not used at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest mutating, i.e. placing quantity inside each product

```js
  increase(product: Product): void {
    product.quantity++;
  }
  decrease(product: Product): void {
    product.quantity--;
  }
```

Comment: that would be direct changes in databse

Answer (score 0):

You can use quantity variable as an array since In the method increase the parameter id is not used at all.

**.ts**

```
export class TestdataComponent implements OnInit {
  quantity = [];
  constructor(private testDataService: TestDataService) {}

  increase(id: any): void {
    this.quantity[id] = parseInt(this.quantity[id]) + 1;
  }
  decrease(id: any): void {
    this.quantity[id] = parseInt(this.quantity[id]) - 1;
  }
}
```

**.html**

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
      <img
        class="card-image"
        src="{{ product.imageUrl }}"
        alt="{{ product.name }}"
      />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{ product.name }}</h5>
        <p class="card-text"><span>price:Rs</span>{{ product.price }}</p>
        <div class="quantity-container">
          <div class="quantity">
            <button
              type="button"
              class="btn quantity-btn"
              (click)="decrease(product._id)"
            >
              <mat-icon>remove</mat-icon>
            </button>
            <span>{{ quantity[product._id] }}</span>
            <button
              type="button"
              class="btn quantity-btn"
              (click)="increase(product._id)"
            >
              <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Then you have to handle db response at your end. Run a loop and push an index ID in each product object. From that index id you can trigger the function and increase each quantity separately.

Comment: i will try this

Comment: i added a property  quantiy(spelling mitake in databse) in database and i changed increase and decrease accordingly but now quantiy is not changing on + 1 or -1 it is sill 0

Comment: Declare a new Object variable in global and copy the response object to that then try again.